# how to separate Array of single element by comma `["275/55R20, 275/60R20"]` this into ["275/55R20", "275/60R20"] in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My array is `sizes = ["275/55R20,  275/60R20"]`
I want to convert it into `sizes = ["275/55R20",  "275/60R20"]`

please someone help to do it in ruby

Answer (score 1):

Use the `split` method on the desired array element:

```
sizes = ["275/55R20,  275/60R20"]
sizes = sizes[0].split(",  ")
#=>  ["275/55R20", "275/60R20"]
```